# Can I detect/see multiple instances of an activity?

Tags: android

I recently fixed a bug where I was spawning multiple instances of the same (standard launch mode) Activity without realizing I was doing it.   I only noticed it in the debugger by counting breakpoint hits in *onCreate(*), *onNewIntent()*, and *onDestroy()*.   I was able to fix it thanks to the many StackOverflow questions on the subject of preventing this problem.

My question is whether there is any way to directly see a list of instances of the Activities in my application, either programmatically or using the Eclipse debugging environment?   This would be useful for both detecting cases where I'm spawning redundant instances or to look for Activity "leaks" where I failed to *finish()* some activity when I was done with it.

(yes, I know I could instrument every Activity but the app I have in mind to look at has over 20 Activities so I'm trying to avoid that)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This somewhat answers your question: [List of all activities in App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084716/list-of-all-activities-in-app)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html

Comment: Will it show duplicates, i.e., multiple instances of the same Activity?

Comment: This answer is wrong. It shows all registered activities and will NOT show multiple instances.