# How to get Activities available of Android apps

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

I need to know what the activities available of a given application are in Android.

I know you can do this: [List of all activities in App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084716/list-of-all-activities-in-app)  but I was wondering if there is a simpler way an also I DONT WANT TO INSTALL THE APP TO SEE AVAILABLE ACTIVITIES

Let's say I want to open Google PlayStore using startapp plugin: https://github.com/lampaa/org.apache.cordova.startapp to download a specific app, then I need to know what activity to use right ?

```
navigator.startApp.start([
    "com.example.hello", // applucation
    "com.example.hello.MainActivity", // activity
    "product_id", // key
    "100" // value
], function(message) { /* success */
    console.log(message); // => OK
}, 
function(error) { /* error */
    console.log('47', error);
});
```

By the way I'm using Cordova and Sencha Touch (if that matters).

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**They are actually listed on AndroidManifest.xml**

And there are a couple of apps that can help you getting the file of installed apps.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.susatthi.ManifestViewer&hl=en