# How to know various activities in an android application

Tags: android, shell, android-activity, adb

I want to see activities of an app downloaded from play store. Basically I want to know the activities of an app so that I can start that application from an android phone or adb.
So far I learned that to start an application we can use,

`$ sudo adb shell am start -n applicationPackageName/.activityName`

eg. `$ sudo adb shell am start -n com.google.android.contacts/.ContactsActivity`

And is there some other way to start an application from terminal from android phone or from adb?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084716/list-of-all-activities-in-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution.

Decompile the app and take a look at the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Actually most developers forget about this option that you can infect start a specific Activity skipping Activities like Login. Make sure you handle stuff like that in your app. Intentionally throwing unhanded `IllegalStatExceptions` for example, effectively crashing it :)

Comment: That was easy. Thank You!

Comment: Yeah. Whether you can skip the login and premium stuff is now up to you :D

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the `Activity Resolver Table:` section of the `dumpsys package <package name>` output:

```
# dumpsys package com.android.contacts
Activity Resolver Table:
  Non-Data Actions:
  com.android.contacts.action.LIST_CONTACTS_WITH_PHONES:
    239ae1c9 com.android.contacts/.activities.PeopleActivity
  com.android.contacts.action.LIST_STREQUENT:
    239ae1c9 com.android.contacts/.activities.PeopleActivity
  android.intent.action.MAIN:
    1b7bebda com.android.contacts/.widget.PinnedHeaderListDemoActivity
    239ae1c9 com.android.contacts/.activities.PeopleActivity
    3e173dd0 com.android.contacts/.NonPhoneActivity
  com.android.contacts.action.LIST_ALL_CONTACTS:
    239ae1c9 com.android.contacts/.activities.PeopleActivity
  com.android.contacts.action.LIST_DEFAULT:
    239ae1c9 com.android.contacts/.activities.PeopleActivity
  com.android.contacts.action.LIST_STARRED:
    239ae1c9 com.android.contacts/.activities.PeopleActivity
  com.android.contacts.action.LIST_FREQUENT:
    239ae1c9 com.android.contacts/.activities.PeopleActivity
  com.android.contacts.action.JOIN_CONTACT:
    54e8f64 com.android.contacts/.activities.ContactSelectionActivity
  com.android.contacts.action.LIST_CONTACTS:
    239ae1c9 com.android.contacts/.activities.PeopleActivity
  android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT:
    480101 com.android.contacts/alias.DialShortcut
    16bceba6 com.android.contacts/alias.MessageShortcut
    1984f6e8 com.android.contacts/.ContactShortcut
  android.intent.action.SEARCH:
    239ae1c9 com.android.contacts/.activities.PeopleActivity
```